# How do I add a website (Google Plus) to the list of apps on Chrome's "New Tab" page?

Tags: google-chrome

Opening a new tab in Chrome gives me a panel of shortcut icons like Gmail, Calendar, etc. Other shortcuts can be added by installing applications from the Store.

I want a link to Google Plus there, but can't find it on the Store. How do I add it manually? Do I have to create a new application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two panels: Recent and apps.<sup>1</sup> If you're looking at "Recent" you just need to visit Google+ more often so that it appears. If you're looking to add to the apps section then the [Google+ Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google%2B/dlppkpafhbajpcmmoheippocdidnckmm) is what you want.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, there can be a bunch of panels if you've installed a lot of apps, but there will always be the "recent" panel.

Comment: awesome thanks. no idea how I was unable to find that extension :|

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the website you want to have shortcut to.
2. Open a new tab, so you can see other shortcuts.
3. Get back to the tab with the website you want to add.

Now it's a little tricky:

There's a website icon on the left side of the addressbar. Start dragging it. First, drag it over the empty tab and wait a second, Chrome will switch to that tab. Don't release the mouse button, move it over other shortcuts and then drop it. A new shortcut should appear.